# How can I subtract hours from a HH:MM AM time string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

What's the best way to subtract a few hours from a time string formatted as such:

```
8:32 AM
```

I thought about splitting the string at the colon but when subtracting 3 hours from, say, 1:00 AM I get -2:00 AM instead of the desired 10:00 PM.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most reliable method is to convert it into a JS date object, then do you math on that

```
var olddate = new Date(2011, 6, 15, 8, 32, 0, 0); // create a date of Jun 15/2011, 8:32:00am

var subbed = new Date(olddate - 3*60*60*1000); // subtract 3 hours

var newtime = subbed.getHours() + ':' + subbed.getMinutes();
```

the Date object accepts either year/month/day/hour/minute/second/milliseconds *OR* a unix-style timestamp of milliseconds-since-Jan-1-1970 for the constructor.

Comment: I was able to generate a unique time stamp from something else so this worked great! Though I did also have to make `0` minutes into `00` minutes and `if (hour > 12) {hour = hour -12}` and something similar for AM/PM.

Answer (score 12):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment("8:32 AM", 'h:mm A').subtract('hours', 2).format('h:mm A')
```

Comment: Just in case if anyone wants the result to be in 24Hr format then in `.format()` use `HH` (caps) instead of `h` or `hh`. I've tried this : `moment("12am", 'hh:mm A').subtract('seconds', 1).format('HHmmss')` for `12am` result is `235959`. Basically format in `.format()` is your choice as mine is `HHmmss` :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to play with only the hours, I think the following would be easy for you:

```
var timeStr = '1:30 PM'
var parts = timeStr.split(':');
var hour = parseInt($.trim(parts[0]));
hour -= 3;

if(hour <= 0){
        // easily flip it by adding 12
    hour += 12;

    // swap am & pm
        if(parts[1].match(/(AM|am)/)){
        parts[1] = parts[1].replace('AM', 'PM').replace('am', 'pm')
            // keep the case
        } else {
            parts[1] = parts[1].replace('PM', 'AM').replace('pm', 'am')
        }
}

// final answer
timeStr = hour + ':' + parts[1];
```

Comment: This returns a negative number when subtracting 3 from 1.

Comment: my result : "10:30 AM"

if hour < 0, it will be added by 12, which make sure the hour is not negative.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that peace of code :

```
 var T1=new Date("September 5, 2005 8:10:00");
var T2=new Date("September 5, 2005 13:35:00");
var diff=new Date();
diff.setTime(T2-T1);
alert(diff.getHours()+":"+diff.getMinutes())
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Its Wrong!, The result of this code is 2:25, and the difference of time for this really is: 13 h 25 m - 8 h 10 m = 5 h 15 m

Answer (score 0):

Hardest part is parsing in your time - I've just added Jan 1, 2009 to the start of the parse method so that it parses it nicely and you don't need to write your own.  (not that it's difficult).  Collapse the code below into a few lines - expanded to show the steps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculateTime(stringTime) {
            var hoursToSubtract = 1;
            var oldTime = Date.parse('Jan 1, 2009 ' + stringTime);
            var newTime = new Date(oldTime - 1000 * 60 * 60 * hoursToSubtract);
            var hours = newTime.getHours();
            var minutes = newTime.getMinutes();
            var designation = "PM";
            if ((hours == 0 || hours == 24) && minutes == 0)
                designation = 'MIDNIGHT';
            else if (hours == 12 && minutes == 0)
                designation = 'NOON'
            else if (hours < 12)
                designation = 'AM';
            else
                hours -= 12;

            document.write('new time = ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + designation );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        calculateTime('8:30 AM');
        calculateTime('8:30 PM');
        calculateTime('12:10 PM');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers on the right track, one more to consider:

```
// Assumes timeString is hh:mm am/pm
function addHours(timeString, h) {
  var t = timeString.match(/\d+/g);
  var am = /am$/.test(timeString);
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(+t[0] + (am? 0 : 12) + +h, +t[1]);
  return formatTime(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes());
}
function formatTime(t) {
  function addZ(n) {
    return n<10? '0'+n : ''+n;
  }

  var t = t.split(':');
  var m = (t[0] > 12)? 'pm' : 'am';

  return addZ(t[0]%12 || t[0]) + ':' + addZ(t[1]) + ' ' + m;
}

 alert( addHours('12:15 am', -13) ); // 11:15 pm
```

Answer (score -1):

You might try a jQuery library like [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/). Below are some examples shown from that link:

```
// Number fun
(3).days().ago();

// Convert text into Date
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

Comment: Date.js is not "a jQuery library", the above doesn't answer the question.